# Stuck at declaring, filling and using a variable in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

In SQL Server, I would this query to define, set and use a variable:

```
declare @teacherId bigint -- declaring

select @teacherId = Id from Teachers where [Name] = 'John' -- filling/setting

select * from Students where TeacherId = @teacherId -- using
```

How can I write that in MariaDB? I'm stuck at it. I constantly get errors and the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/) is extremely unhelpful and lacks examples. I tried:

```
declare @teacherId

select Id into @teacherId from Teachers where `Name` = 'John'
```

But it has errors.

**Update**:

The error is:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'declare @teacherId select Id into @teacherId from Teachers where `Name` ...' at line 1

Comment: What are the errors? (please add them to the question for formatting, NOT in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need variables to do that. Join the tables

```
select * 
from Students 
join Teachers 
on Students.TeacherID = Students.TeacherID 
where Teachers.Name= 'John'
```

MariaDB does have stored procedures, where you can use variables. Please see their documentation.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-routines/

Comment: I need to use that variable later in my code. Of course I just provided a simple example to  clearly define the problem in a simple way. It's a long query and I need to fill some variables in the beginning.

Comment: SQL is a powerful language and most queries are possible without resorting to variables and procedures.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this specific problem.